# Select columns in dplyr conditionally

Tags: r, select, dplyr

```
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)

head(flights)

id.vec <- c("a", "b", "c")

for(i in seq_along(id.vec)){

  id <- id.vec[i]

  temp <- flights %>% dplyr::select(year, day, dep_time, arr_time) %>%
                      dplyr::mutate(year = year - mean(year),
                                    day = day - mean(day),
                                    dep_time = dep_time - mean(dep_time),
                                    arr_time = arr_time - mean(arr_time))

  # do some other tasks with temp file
}
```

My question is how can I put a condition that if `id == "c"`, then do not 
select the `dep_time` column and also do not execute the `dep_time = dep_time - mean(dep_time)`

Comment: I am not sure if the questions are similar. Anyway I will have a look

Comment: If there are only 3 ids then easy solution would be `if` `else` `if` etc.

Comment: Actually I have more than 3 ids

Answer (score -1):

A simple option would be to include an if... else... statement in the for loop:

```
for(i in seq_along(id.vec)){


  id <- id.vec[i]

  if(id == 'c') {
  temp <- flights %>% dplyr::select(year, day, arr_time) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(year = year - mean(year),
                  day = day - mean(day),
                  arr_time = arr_time - mean(arr_time))
  } else {
    temp <- flights %>% dplyr::select(year, day, dep_time, arr_time) %>%
      dplyr::mutate(year = year - mean(year),
                    day = day - mean(day),
                    dep_time = dep_time - mean(dep_time),
                    arr_time = arr_time - mean(arr_time))
  }

  # do some other tasks with temp file
}
```