# Conditionally add column to groupby in dplyr R

Tags: r, dplyr

This question here - [Select columns in dplyr conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52985795/select-columns-in-dplyr-conditionally) - is related to my question, but I don't consider the answer to be satisfactory. I have the following line of code:

```
doAGroupBy <- function(data, some_condition) {

  # assume all columns used in filter/group_by are always in data
  new.data <- data %>%
    dplyr::group_by(player, team, game, season) %>%
    dplyr::summarise( ... )

  return(new.data)
}
```

My question is this - I would like to only add `game` as one of the grouping variables when `some_condition == TRUE`, otherwise I would like to group_by only the other 3 variables. Is this possible without having two separate dplyr chains - one in an `if` case and the other in an `else` case (as is done in the link above). My dplyr chain is long-ish, and identical other than the group_by, and repeating all of the code twice just for the group_by is not DRY.

Thanks for help with this!!

Comment: my dplyr chain is not as long as expected and I will actually likely just go with the if-else case - will leave the Q open as a good answer would be interesting to see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `mtcars` for a toy example, and `group_by_at` to solve your problem.

```r
library(tidyverse)

doAGroupBy <- function(data, some_condition) {

  if (some_condition == TRUE) {

    group_args <- c("cyl","carb","disp","hp")

  } else {

    group_args <-  c("cyl","carb","disp")

  }

  data %>%
    dplyr::group_by_at(group_args) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(mpg = mean(mpg))
}

doAGroupBy(mtcars, FALSE)
#> # A tibble: 28 x 4
#> # Groups:   cyl, carb [?]
#>      cyl  carb  disp   mpg
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     4     1  71.1  33.9
#>  2     4     1  78.7  32.4
#>  3     4     1  79    27.3
#>  4     4     1 108    22.8
#>  5     4     1 120.   21.5
#>  6     4     2  75.7  30.4
#>  7     4     2  95.1  30.4
#>  8     4     2 120.   26  
#>  9     4     2 121    21.4
#> 10     4     2 141.   22.8
#> # ... with 18 more rows

doAGroupBy(mtcars, TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 28 x 5
#> # Groups:   cyl, carb, disp [?]
#>      cyl  carb  disp    hp   mpg
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     4     1  71.1    65  33.9
#>  2     4     1  78.7    66  32.4
#>  3     4     1  79      66  27.3
#>  4     4     1 108      93  22.8
#>  5     4     1 120.     97  21.5
#>  6     4     2  75.7    52  30.4
#>  7     4     2  95.1   113  30.4
#>  8     4     2 120.     91  26  
#>  9     4     2 121     109  21.4
#> 10     4     2 141.     95  22.8
#> # ... with 18 more rows
```

Comment: You can also move conditionals inside the `group_by_at`. This will work the same way and might be more easily expandable: `dplyr::group_by_at(c("cyl","carb","disp",if(some_condition)"hp"))`

Comment: big fan of this approach, didnt know about `group_by_at` - thanks!

Comment: For those like me who found this useful a few years later, I see that in the meanwhile, group_by_at(...) is now superseded by group_by(pick(...)).

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this scale well and work outside of just this one data frame you have, you can take a [non-standard evaluation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) / tidyeval approach and write a function that adjusts its `group_by` call based on some condition argument. This seems like a common enough use-case that it's work developing a function—I've done similar conditional grouping in functions I wrote for a personal/work package, and would love to see similar `*_at_if` functions adopted into `dplyr`.

Here's an example with the `mpg` data that ships with `ggplot2`. In the function `group_conditional`, I'm making quosures of 2 sets of columns: one that will always be used for grouping, supplied as bare column names in `...`, and one that will be used for grouping if `condition` is true, supplied as a character vector of column names.

```r
library(tidyverse)

group_conditional <- function(.data, ..., conditional_cols, condition) {
  base_group_vars <- quos(...)
  conditional_group_vars <- syms(conditional_cols)
  if (condition) {
    .data %>%
      group_by(!!!base_group_vars, !!!conditional_group_vars)
  } else {
    .data %>%
      group_by(!!!base_group_vars)
  }
}
```

You can see here that grouping is based on a simple true/false supplied to `condition`:

```r
mpg %>%
  group_conditional(manufacturer, year, 
                    conditional_cols = c("class", "trans"), 
                    condition = T) %>%
  head()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 11
#> # Groups:   manufacturer, year, class, trans [4]
#>   manufacturer model displ  year   cyl trans  drv     cty   hwy fl    class
#>   <chr>        <chr> <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>  <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 audi         a4      1.8  1999     4 auto(… f        18    29 p     comp…
#> 2 audi         a4      1.8  1999     4 manua… f        21    29 p     comp…
#> 3 audi         a4      2    2008     4 manua… f        20    31 p     comp…
#> 4 audi         a4      2    2008     4 auto(… f        21    30 p     comp…
#> 5 audi         a4      2.8  1999     6 auto(… f        16    26 p     comp…
#> 6 audi         a4      2.8  1999     6 manua… f        18    26 p     comp…

mpg %>%
  group_conditional(manufacturer, year, 
                    conditional_cols = c("class", "trans"), 
                    condition = F) %>%
  head()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 11
#> # Groups:   manufacturer, year [2]
#>   manufacturer model displ  year   cyl trans  drv     cty   hwy fl    class
#>   <chr>        <chr> <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>  <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 audi         a4      1.8  1999     4 auto(… f        18    29 p     comp…
#> 2 audi         a4      1.8  1999     4 manua… f        21    29 p     comp…
#> 3 audi         a4      2    2008     4 manua… f        20    31 p     comp…
#> 4 audi         a4      2    2008     4 auto(… f        21    30 p     comp…
#> 5 audi         a4      2.8  1999     6 auto(… f        16    26 p     comp…
#> 6 audi         a4      2.8  1999     6 manua… f        18    26 p     comp…
```

Obviously you can use more complicated conditions. Here I'm only grouping by the conditional columns if there are more than 8 distinct values of `mpg$class` (there aren't, so the condition is false):

```r
mpg %>%
  group_conditional(manufacturer, year, 
                    conditional_cols = c("class", "trans"), 
                    condition = n_distinct(mpg$class) > 8) %>%
  head()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 11
#> # Groups:   manufacturer, year [2]
#>   manufacturer model displ  year   cyl trans  drv     cty   hwy fl    class
#>   <chr>        <chr> <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>  <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 audi         a4      1.8  1999     4 auto(… f        18    29 p     comp…
#> 2 audi         a4      1.8  1999     4 manua… f        21    29 p     comp…
#> 3 audi         a4      2    2008     4 manua… f        20    31 p     comp…
#> 4 audi         a4      2    2008     4 auto(… f        21    30 p     comp…
#> 5 audi         a4      2.8  1999     6 auto(… f        16    26 p     comp…
#> 6 audi         a4      2.8  1999     6 manua… f        18    26 p     comp…
```

Your next step might be a call to `summarise_all`, `summarise_if`, or something similar:

```r
mpg %>%
  group_conditional(manufacturer, year, 
                    conditional_cols = c("class", "trans"), 
                    condition = T) %>%
  summarise_if(is.numeric, mean) %>%
  head()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 8
#> # Groups:   manufacturer, year, class [3]
#>   manufacturer  year class   trans      displ   cyl   cty   hwy
#>   <chr>        <int> <chr>   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 audi          1999 compact auto(l5)    2.3   5     16.2  26.2
#> 2 audi          1999 compact manual(m5)  2.3   5     18.5  26.5
#> 3 audi          1999 midsize auto(l5)    2.8   6     15    24  
#> 4 audi          2008 compact auto(av)    2.55  5     19.5  28.5
#> 5 audi          2008 compact auto(s6)    2.55  5     18    26  
#> 6 audi          2008 compact manual(m6)  2.37  4.67  18.3  28
```